# getReasonPhrase() in HTTP for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In Android we can use `getReasonPhrase()` in HTTP Client:

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
System.print.out(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
```

Which can be `ok`, `Not Found`, `Created` or whatever from Web Service.

How we can get it in Objective-C ?

This is the way that I could receive the `status Code`:

```
NSURLResponse *resp
NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)resp;
int responseStatusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
NSLog(@"%i", responseStatusCode);
```

How about `getReasonPhrase()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *reasonString = [NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:responseStatusCode];
```

Cheers